# Unable to get matched answer using factorization

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I have question to solve by factorization.

the question is $$(a+b)x^2 + (a+2b+c)x + (b+c) = 0$$ 
the answer should be $$x = -a, -b.$$

i have done using it

\begin{align}
(a+b)x^2 + (a+b+b+c)x + (b+c) &= 0 \\
(a+b)x^2 + ((a+b)+(b+c))x + (b+c) &= 0\\
(a+b)x^2 + (a+b)x+(b+c)x + (b+c) &= 0\\
x(a+b)[x+1] +(b+c)[x+1] &= 0\\
(x+1)(x(a+b)+(b+c)) &= 0\\
\\
x+1 &= 0\\
x(a+b)+(b+c) &= 0
\end{align}

Comment: The problem, as stated, is wrong, since $x = -1$ is a solution, as you have correctly shown in your work.

Comment: Your solution is perfectly correct ! Well done and wrong statement of the problem.

Comment: The final step you might want to take is to say that $x = -frac{b+c}{a+b}$, is another solution, provided $a + b \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers are correct, and the original answer, unfortunately, is wrong; as you found, the roots of the polynomial are $$x=-1,-\frac{b+c}{a+b},$$ assuming $a+b\ne0$. Also, that was some clever factoring you employed!